# SQL Order by date, then change the value of id with update function

Tags: sql, sorting

This my first time when I use SQL and I need your help. I have got a table like this:

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.02.2021 |
| 2 | 03.02.2021 |
| 3 | 04.02.2021 |
| 4 | 02.02.2021 |

And I can order it by date, then I have got this:

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.02.2021 |
| 4 | 02.02.2021 |
| 2 | 03.02.2021 |
| 3 | 04.02.2021 |

I have done this with function UPDATE and ORDER BY. There is a question now. How to order by date, and change the value of ID with update function to get the result like this:

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.02.2021 |
| 2 | 02.02.2021 |
| 3 | 03.02.2021 |
| 4 | 04.02.2021 |

Is there any quick method to sort by date and leave the order of ID? I want to help my friend with that but I have never been working with SQL. Sorry for my english.

Comment: You don't. Keep it as it is.

Comment: Do you want a result set like this or you need the table to be updated like this?

Comment: You already have an ordering column, `date` . Why you need the second column with the same ordering?

Comment: I want the table to be updated like this. At first I want to order it with date and then assign ID ascending from 1 to the end to get the reselut as you can see in the last table

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
UPDATE table t
SET t.id = t1.NEW_ID
FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS New_ID
      FROM TABLE
 ) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
with my_cte as (
select id, date
, row_number() over(order by date asc) rn 
from test
)
update test set id = 
(select  min(rn) from my_cte 
where test.id = my_cte.id and test.date=my_cte.date);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Edit the table (Right Click >> Design)**

1. Remove Primary Key.
2. Disable Identity (Set it to No).
3. Save the changes.

- Change [OLD_SYS_ID] to your Column name.
- Change [T_Requests_New] to your Table name.
- Execute the code below after the above modifications.
- **Rollback Step 1,2 and save the changes.**

  ```
   with ORG_Table as (select OLD_SYS_ID,row_number() over(order by OLD_SYS_ID asc) New_ID from T_Requests_New) update T_Requests_New set ID = (select  New_ID from ORG_Table where T_Requests_New.OLD_SYS_ID = ORG_Table.OLD_SYS_ID);
  ```